# Format String Visualforce Component in a Custom Visualforce Template

Tags: visualforce-component, date, vf-email-template

I am struggling with something I think should not be difficult but I am not able to figure out, my date field display as the below screenshot.

[image]

My aim is to remove from the template the characters **00:00:00 GMT 2020**  The field is date type, and I am sending to the visualforce component in the following way, then the visualforce component  read the field as String

**Email Template Content**:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="User" relatedToType="SBQQ__Quote__c" subject="Quote {!relatedTo.Name} requires Trial Request">   
    
<messaging:htmlEmailBody > 

     <c:CPQComponent quoteId="{!relatedTo.id}" accountName="{!relatedTo.SBQQ__Account__r.Name}" 
                                    quoteNetAmount="{!relatedTo.SBQQ__NetAmount__c}" 
                                    salesRep="{!relatedTo.SBQQ__SalesRep__r.Name}" 
                                    recipientName="{!recipient.name}" 
                                    primaryContact="{!relatedTo.SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c}" 
                                    trialRequestShipDate="{!relatedTo.Requested_Ship_Date__c}" 
                                    />                        
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**Visualforce Component Portion Code:**

```
<apex:component controller="CPQ_CSTrialRequestController" access="global">
<apex:attribute name ="trialRequestShipDate" type="String" description="Trial Requested Ship Date" assignTo="{!quote_TrialRequestShipDate}"/>
```

```
<font color="#58595b" face="Arial,Verdana,Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif" style="font-size:16px; line-height: 24px;">{!quote_TrialStartDate}</font></td>
```

Do you recommend me other approach?

Thanks!

Comment: is `Requested_Ship_Date__c` really a Text data type and not a Date datatype?

Comment: It is a Date datatype

Comment: Then the component data type should be Date and you can use standard date formatting via apex:Param to get what you need

Comment: Thank you for your support. @cropredy.  I changed to Date but I am facing now the following error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text. I think i faced before I tried with Date type

Comment: your component controller property called `trialRequestShipDate` needs to use `Date` as well; I presume you know about [VF formatting dates using outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm?search_text=outputText)

Comment: Yes,I am aware about outputext. I have fixed the component and it is running properly now thank you very much  @cropredy. I missed to updated the controller (facepalm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue:

The field passed to the VF component is of type `Date`

```
trialRequestShipDate="{!relatedTo.Requested_Ship_Date__c}
```

The component defines it as type `String`

```
<apex:attribute name ="trialRequestShipDate" type="String"
```

And the VF Component controller would also have been defined as type `String`

```
public String trialRequestShipDate {get; set;}
```

To fix, both the `<apex:attribute>` and the VF component property should be of type `Date`

You'll then be able to easily format the value as you want using `<apex:outputText>` using this [VF field formatting reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm?search_text=outputText)